# Create kea runtime directory at startup in Yocto image

Tags: linux, yocto, bitbake, init.d

I need to get Kea (DHCP server) running automatically at startup in my Yocto-based project. The Yocto recipe already includes an init.d script to start Kea automatically, however Kea requires a directory /var/run/kea to exist in order to run, so the startup script fails. Since directories under /var/run do not persist, this directory needs to be created at each startup. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to add `mkdir -p /var/run/kea` to the `kea-dhcp4-server` script under `init.d`.
(I had already tried this but forgot to set execute permission on `kea-dhcp4-server` in my .bbappend).